# Unix ksh sqlplus displaying leading zero for decimal numbers

Tags: unix, plsql, ksh

I'm stuck with the following:

I have a SQL query in a ksh and for the values like 0.23, 0.55 it displays only .23 .55.

Anyone have a idea ? There is some parameters to set ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select numbers without explicitly converting them to strings, you'll get the default number format which tries to show the number's significant digits using the least number of characters.

Wrap the numeric columns in `TO_CHAR()` calls with the format you want:

```
SQL> select to_char(.12, '0.99') from dual;

TO_CH
-----
 0.12
```